# Dynamically generated buttons have same label?

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, dynamically-generated

Dynamically generating buttons and storing them using shared preferences. After creating buttons changing their label using `EditText` and setting button label by `myButton.setText(input.getText());`. Also using another `Shared Preference to store their label`.
code to Create buttons:

```
final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("New");
        btn1.getId();       
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mDialog(btn1.getText().toString());
            }
        });
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        ll.addView(btn1, lp);
        count++;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", count);
        editor.commit();
btn1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                mdialog.setView(input);
```

using button to save label changes

```
btn1.setText(input.getText());
                        Editor edit = preference.edit();
                        edit.putString("key",btn1.getText().toString());
                        edit.commit();
```

Code for `Shared Preference` defined in oncreate method

```
preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    count=prefs.getInt("count", 0);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        final Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mDialog(myButton.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        myButton.getId();
        myButton.setText(preference.getString("key","New"));
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        myButton.setText(input.getText());
                        Editor edit = preference.edit();
                        edit.putString("key", myButton.getText().toString());
                        edit.commit();
                    }
                });
ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

Comment: you mean the text you save in the preferences is always the same ?

Comment: because you always save your value with same key, you need unique key for each label

Comment: @Amrola yes once I rename all buttons with different text(clothing, acessories, shoes etc.) but when restart application all buttons have same text(shoes).

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan can you tell me how to solve this if possible

Comment: you need store last id that used for your saving, then you need ++ that to get another unique key

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan where i need to store last id and then use ++ to get another unique id

Comment: you can use one int, then after saving your label with that int, increment that, if you want int value even after closing app for create one another label, then you need save your int in sharepreference too, then before create one another label, just ge that, increment, and save your value

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan I'm using 'int i' for creating buttons, btn1.setId(i) after in oncreate method using 'int j' for shared pereference to store buttons , mybutton.setId(j, j++). still no desired result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46811/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-user3172071)

Comment: @Amrola can you help with this?

Comment: the "key" in your SharedPreferences is always the same , try to give a different key for each button .

Comment: @Amrola how to give different "key" as buttons are generated programatically. Here the problem is when i create three buttons naming test1, test2, test3 and restart the app. all the buttons have test3 as Button label(text)

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the last button name to be the name for all the buttons :

```
edit.putString("key",btn1.getText().toString());
```

so you are saving everything with the "key" so you are using the last saved key for all of the buttons .

what you can do is the following :

1st - use a database to save the names of the buttons .

2nd - if your application API is greater than 11

use the SharedPreferences.Editor `putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)` 
here you will give one key , a multiple values , so you can save all your button names

and please give me feedback .

Hope that helps

Comment: The method putStringSet(String, Set<String>) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: I'm new to android so don't know that much can you help with a piece of code

Comment: give me time to implement that .

Comment: check my answer and confirm ?

Comment: I'm not able to view your answer

Comment: min 8, but where is your answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46831/discussion-between-amrola-and-user3172071)